# Ksh - Declare type (OOP) through ssh command

Tags: shell, object, ssh, ksh

I'm trying to declare a type (class) remotely through ssh before instantiating it. Is there perhaps a way to serialize a type ?

The following is a simplified REPRODUCTIBLE example (no constructor).

Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/ksh

typeset -T SubConfiguration_t=(
    dirs=(
        bin="binDir"
        lib="libDir"
    )

    ports=(
        ssh="22"
    )
)

typeset -T Configuration_t=(
    test=(
        hello="hello world !"
    )
    SubConfiguration sub=()
)


ssh user@host /bin/ksh << EOF
    set -x
    $(typeset -p .sh.type.SubConfiguration_t) # This outputs: typeset -r -b -L 4 .sh.type.SubConfiguration=(dirs=(bin=binDir;lib=libDir;)ports=(ssh=22))
    $(typeset -p .sh.type.Configuration_t)    # Same pattern
    Configuration_t config
    echo ${config.sub.dirs.lib}
EOF
```

output:

```
+ .sh.type.SubConfiguration_t.dirs.bin=binDir
+ .sh.type.SubConfiguration_t.dirs.lib=libDir
+ .sh.type.SubConfiguration_t.ports.ssh=22
+ typeset -r -b -L 4 .sh.type.SubConfiguration_t
Usage: typeset [-bflmnprstuxACHS] [-a[type]] [-i[base]] [-E[n]] [-F[n]] [-L[n]]
               [-M[mapping]] [-R[n]] [-X[n]] [-h string] [-T[tname]] [-Z[n]]
               [name[=value]...]
   Or: typeset [ options ] -f [name...]
```

Comment: If you want to see what's happening (and thereby provide enough debugging info to make your question answerable), add a `-x` to your remote shell invocation (and run `set -x` on the local one before the ssh invocation), and add the output to your question. Note that we expect a [mre] -- the shortest code that can be run _without changes_ to demonstrate a problem or test a proposed fix.

Comment: (if the immediate problem is that `typeset -p .sh.type.SubConfiguration_t` doesn't emit the output you expect, show that in the question! And please describe the specific ksh release this code is expected to run with -- I assume it's ksh93, but we don't want people coming in and trying to test with mksh unless it's expected to be supported there).

Comment: ...anyhow, as for doing this the way way... have you considered moving your type definitions into a library you could just copy onto the wire?

Comment: Does the library have to be written in C ? If so then no. If I were allowed to write C I wouldn't have used shell in the first place.

Comment: The example is reproductible btw. Just use your user and host for the ssh command.

Comment: By "library" I meant a ksh file you can source.

Comment: I like your workaround. I was hoping to be able to serialize types but if it can't be one there's no helping it..

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit late with my answer.
In shells you can source pieces of code.
Create in the same directory for each type a separate file, a test script file, then run test_ssh.ksh.
I wouldn't recommend manipulating .sh.type namespace directly.

**SubConfiguration_t** file:

```
typeset -T SubConfiguration_t=(
    dirs=(
        bin="binDir"
        lib="libDir"
    )

    ports=(
        ssh="22"
    )
)
```

**Configuration_t** file:

```
typeset -T Configuration_t=(
    test=(
        hello="hello world !"
    )
    SubConfiguration_t sub=()
)
```

**test_ssh.ksh** file:

```
#!/bin/ksh

scrpt=${0##*/}
scrptDir=${0%/*}

ssh user@host /bin/ksh << EOF
    set -x
#
# source types here
#
${ < ${scrptDir}/SubConfiguration_t;}
${ < ${scrptDir}/Configuration_t;}
#
# source script code here
#
    typeset -p .sh.type.SubConfiguration_t
    typeset -p .sh.type.Configuration_t
    typeset -p .sh.type

    Configuration_t config

    typeset -p config

    echo \${config.sub.dirs.lib}
EOF
```